# Problema con cron y command laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, cron

Estoy programando envío de correos mediante comando en laravel.  Al incorporar la ejecución en mi archivo cron, éste se ejecuta en la frecuencia indicada en el cron y no en el schedule indicado de mi comando

```
   En el cron:::::
    * * * * * php /var/www/test-gestionventa/artisan sms:birthday 1>> /dev/null 2>&1


  En mi class Kernel:::::::
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {
    $schedule->command('sms:birthday')->everyFiveMinutes();
   }
```

¿Cómo hago para el cron se ejecute cada 5 minutos como lo indico en mi clase y no cada minuto como está en cron?  **sin tener que especificarle la misma frecuencia (cada 5 minutos) en cron**

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes q programar un cron en el servidor para hacer una tarea en concreto, el cron q tiene q ejecutar el servidor es este :

```
* * * * * php /ruta-hacia-tu-artisan/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Una vez este ese cron programado en el server, ya puedes declarar los crons donde comentas en el archivo app\Console\Kernel.php.

```
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {
    $schedule->command('sms:birthday')->everyFiveMinutes(); //se ejecutara cada 5 mins
    $schedule->command('sms:otro')->daily(); //se ejecutara diariamente
   }
```

Comment: Gracias! Estaba confundida, hay que hacer referencia al schedule y no al comando en si. Agradecida por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Virginia si te ha ayudado vota la respuesta como correcta! Un saludo!